# Hooking audio compressor to mains without chasis

Tags: power, grounding

I am nearing the completion of my DIY compressor project, and I have a rather seemingly basic question..

Once I hook up my toroid and everything, since I don't have my 19" 1U rack enclosure yet, but would like to test my projects for any problems, is it safe enough to find a metal piece somewhere, put a lug, and attach all my grounding to it?

I should also add that the compressor is the GSSL project and is all solid state design. No tubes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and do you have a schematic?

Comment: @Andy here is the schematic http://www.gyraf.dk/gy_pd/ssl/ssl_sch.gif and basically all I want to figure out is, is it safe for me to plug it in to the mains without having a fully enclosed chasis? Because I know I have to make chasis grounds, but since I don't have it yet and want to know if it'll work/turn on, I was wondering if a relatively big scrap metal is okay to use as the ground. Basically to make a lug in it and hook all of my grounding wires

Comment: Electrically it's fine and will operate, but exposed mains wiriring is obviously a safety hazard. I love how that schematic says "220v or whatever" as the mains input

Comment: This..... is an audio compressor? I assumed it was a air compressor from the title. Maybe clarify a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Have exposed mains is dangerous, and I expect you know that. This answer only talks about *how* to do it, not *if you should* do it!

That being said...

You do want to bring all of your grounds together. This can be to any piece of random metal that you can firmly connect them to.  If you had ring terminals, I could envision each ground wire being terminated with a ring terminal, and all the ring terminals connected around a bolt with a washer and nut.

Don't forget to hook up this big node of wires up to the ground wire in your mains!  It doesn't do any good if it's floating.  And, of course, make sure it can't make accidental contact with the live circuitry.

Also, for a project like this, I always try to plug it into a GFCI outlet.  If you don't have one available, you can find an extension cord with an integrated GFCI.  This way, it ensures that your ground node won't get "hot", in case anything goes wrong...

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you.. One last question (as a thought experiment I suppose) -- if I shrink tube all the exposed wires from my toroid soldered to the AC plug, so that it is not exposed from the toroid to the power cord to the wall, will that make it "safer" or perhaps just nothing but a very marginal difference?